# Last few lines of CSV file gets cut off

Tags: c#, io

I have the following program that runs on specified csv files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:/Documents and Settings/expn261/Desktop/SAPHR_Joiners_20110812.csv";
        string strCharater = File.ReadAllText(path,UTF7Encoding.UTF7);

        strCharater = strCharater.ToString();

        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[èéèëêð]", "e");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÉÈËÊ]", "E");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[àâä]", "a");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]", "A");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[àáâãäå]", "a");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÙÚÛÜ]", "U");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ùúûüµ]", "u");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[òóôõöø]", "o");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÒÓÔÕÖØ]", "O");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ìíîï]", "i");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÌÍÎÏ]", "I");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[š]", "s");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Š]", "S");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ñ]", "n");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Ñ]", "N");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ç]", "c");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Ç]", "C");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ÿ]", "y");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Ÿ]", "Y");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[ž]", "z");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Ž]", "Z");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Ð]", "D");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[œ]", "oe");
        strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[Œ]", "Oe");
        //strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[«»\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]", "\"");
        //strCharater = Regex.Replace(strCharater, "[\u2026]", "...");

        string path2 = (@"C:/Documents and Settings/expn261/Desktop/file.csv");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path2);
        sw.WriteLine(strCharater,UTF7Encoding.UTF7);
    }
}
```

The problem is that no matter which file I run it on the last 3 or 4 lines are not displayed.

What could the problem be?

Comment: You aren't closing your streamwriter.

Comment: I wasn't going to answer until Hinek did.  His answer is the 'cure' but does not explain the problem.  You are not closing your streamwriter, so its not writing its buffer out.  You could call Close() on the stream, but the pattern of Using(){} is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use IDisposables as the `StreamWriter` in using(){}, like:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path2))
{
    sw.WriteLine(strCharater, UTF7Encoding.UTF7);
}
```

In this case, the clean dispose will call the `Close()` method of the `StreamWriter` which will cause it to write it's buffer to the file.